# Use VPN to connect to different computers

Tags: windows, vpn

I'm a newbie on these topics, so sorry for any mistake/error I make while explaining.

I need to create a connection between my computer and n computers, so I can connect to them when I need to. I searched on Internet and found about VPN but it didn't do exactly what I need, or maybe yes but I couldn't understand it or figure out how.

What I need is similar to LogMeIn, a list of computers which I can connect to.

Is there some way to do it? Are there any free/opensource software that can do it?

The computers are all Windows Server 2003 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best soft I found when I stopped using LogMeIn was Teamviewer, still using it ! 
And it is free for personal use:

https://www.teamviewer.com

Otherwise, you would indeed need VPN to connect your computer on the same network, and then allow remote access. 
Teamviewer allows you to do that without the VPN part, as LogMeIn would (But I find it easier to use). You can start TeamViewer on each computer as service, and then access them whenever you want with a user and password.